# Azure Application Insights Angular Prevent Certain Data from Logging

Tags: angular, azure-application-insights

I'm using Azure Application Insights in my Angular App to log client side interactions.

https://github.com/TrilonIO/angular-application-insights

I'm trying to prevent a certain URL 404 from being logged to Application Insights.

Is there a way to hook into what data is being sent to App Insights, check for the Url in question, and prevent sending?

Below is code I am using in App Component to initialize.

```
                appInsightsService.config = {
                    instrumentationKey: 'appkey'
                }
                appInsightsService.init();

                // associate user
                appInsightsService.setAuthenticatedUserContext(user.name, user.account, true);
```

In no where in the Angular code am I explicitly calling any App Insight logging methods.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming , you must have create an application insight service something like below:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AppInsights} from 'applicationinsights-js';

@Injectable()
export class MonitoringService {
  private config: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.IConfig = {
    instrumentationKey: 'KEY_GOES_HERE',
    enableDebug: true,
    verboseLogging: true
  };

  constructor() {
    if (!AppInsights.config) {
      AppInsights.downloadAndSetup(this.config);
    }
  }

  logPageView(name?: string, url?: string, properties?: any, measurements?: any, duration?: number) {
    AppInsights.trackPageView(name, url, properties, measurements, duration);
  }

  logEvent(name: string, properties?: any, measurements?: any) {
    AppInsights.trackEvent(name, properties, measurements);
  }

  trackException(exception: Error) {
    AppInsights.trackException(exception);
  }
}
```

Angular handles all the uncaught exceptions so it must be storing all the 404 too. Try implementing an https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler and call trackException from there.

this will be a custom error handler from where you can filter tht URL which you want to store also you can check the response code of 404. If it's true then no need to save it else just simply call track exception method.

Here is one good article for configuring  AI in angular SPA.

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/using-azure-application-insights-with-single-page-apps

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated my answer. No where am I explicitly calling any logging methods like your example of trackException, logEvent. It appears the App Insights code is automatically handling capturing the 404 error and logging to Azure. With that being said, how do I prevent automatic logging of that particular exception.

Answer (score 0):

Our `angular-application-insights` packages actually automatically logs all URLs to Azure application insights.

You can disable this functionality by passing 
`overrideTrackPageMetrics: true` to the config

```
appInsightsService.config = {
  overrideTrackPageMetrics: true, // <-- 
  // other things
}
```

You can place similar to code to what I have [here from the package itself](https://github.com/TrilonIO/angular-application-insights/blob/master/src/app-insight.service.ts#L308), and handle Route logging on your own afterwards!

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Hi Mark. Can you provide an example on how you would handle logging? Not sure i fully understand